# this.state not showing in html

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Most likely I'm doing this wrong, when I console.log this.state.name and email it shows up in the console but when I render it doesn't show up. I'm vey new to react so please excuse the code, if there is a better method of doing this please show me. what Im trying to do here is fetch a profile page from an axios.get request (profilePage) and display this data on the page

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { profilePage } from '../UserFunctions'

export default class Profile extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      //Set default message
      this.state = {
        param: null,
        message: 'Loading...',
        name: '',
        email: ''
      }
    } 

    componentDidMount() {
      let Paramvalue=this.props.match.params.id;
      this.state.param = Paramvalue

      var user = this.state.param
      profilePage(user).then(res => {
        this.state.name = res.data[0].fname + ' ' + res.data[0].lname
        this.state.email = res.data[0].email
        console.log(this.state.name)
      })

    }
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Home</h1>
          <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
          <h1>{this.state.email}</h1>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: there's a big no no in react: **never mutate state directly**. Use `setState`

Answer (score 2):

this is because you are directly mutating the state object instead of calling `setState` so a re-render is not triggered. Here is a modified version of your code which should work as expected.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { profilePage } from '../UserFunctions'

export default class Profile extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      //Set default message
      this.state = {
        param: null,
        message: 'Loading...',
        name: '',
        email: ''
      }
    } 

    componentDidMount() {
      let user=this.props.match.params.id;
      profilePage(user).then(res => {
        this.setState({
          name: res.data[0].fname + ' ' + res.data[0].lname,
          email: res.data[0].email,
          param: user,
        });
      })

    }
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Home</h1>
          <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
          <h1>{this.state.email}</h1>
        </div>
      );
  }
}
```